Parcel Build does not output a folder
I have a problem with parcel.
When I run the build script, nothing really happens. Actually, it says that it built something but it never gives the output folder out.
I tried everything, but nothing seems to work for me(I put --dist-dir, --public-url etc.). I paste here the .json file, where I guess the error is.
Please if someone experienced the same share with me the solution.
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel serve ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js/bundled",
"build": "parcel build './views/*.ejs'"

  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/resolver-glob": "^2.12.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.3",
    "parcel": "^2.12.0",
    "parcel-plugin-electron-dotenv": "^0.1.0",
    "parcel-transformer-ejs": "^1.0.1",

    "@parcel/config-default": "^2.12.0",
    "@parcel/core": "^2.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    
    "canvas-image-cover": "^2.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "gsap": "^3.12.5"
  }
  
}



you should include the log/output too, this might not be enough to guess what's wrong
